# When can we make a change of variables $f'$ for $f$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

In my applied math class, my instructor introduced the example of two point masses, both with mass $m$, with positions $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$. Newton's law gives us the differential equation

$$r'' + (2Gm)r^{-2} = 0,$$

where $r(t) : = |x_1(t) - x_2(t)|$.

My instructor told us that we can solve this diff EQ by changing variables and noting that

$$r'' = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{dr}{dt} =\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt},$$

so

$$v\,dv =2Gm \frac{dr}{r^2}$$

and we can integrate.

**My Question:**

I'm troubled by this change of variables. We are assuming that there is a function $v(r)$. Am I correct that this is a physical assumption and not a mathematical one? (For instance, if two things were oscillating with some irregularity, there would not be a well-defined $v(r)$, right?) What allows us to make that assumption here? (It seems clear that the particles will simply come toward each other and then collide, but I'm trying to be precise.)

Comment: Your instructor is setting $r'(t)=v(t)$, it seems.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I think that is the definition of $v$, right? Am I incorrect that he's defining a function $v(r)$?

Comment: If $r$ is a continuously twice differentiable function $r=r(t)$ of $t$ on some interval (a fair assumption in a physical situation), where $dr/dt$ is non-zero in this interval, then the inverse function theorem gives you the existence of a differentiable inverse function $t=t(r)$. Then you can simply apply chain rule to the function $v(t(r))$. An oscillatory solution may well exist, but the distinct oscillations in this neighborhood will fall outside the chosen interval, so the problem does not arise.

Comment: (cont'd)  In math courses you have surely effortlessly applied implicit function theorem in upper/lower hemisphere/circle. There similarly restricting the function to a small region of the variable space saves the day.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Very clear, thank you! I wonder why they did not mention this important fact; I am sure that many students missed it, unless they are just so used to it.

Comment: My experience from physics courses/texts is that they simply ignore such details and concentrate on the physical interpretation of derivatives and such.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$r'' + (2Gm)r^{-2} = 0,$$

can be written as $$r'r''=-2Gm\frac{r'}{r^2}$$

Integration gives $$\frac 1 2r'^2=2Gm r^{-1}$$ so $$rr'^2=4Gm$$ I wouldn't know what was intended after this.

Comment: What is the meaning of the term $\frac{dv}{dr}$ that my instructor wrote?

Comment: @EricAuld My wildest guess is it is some form of the chain rule. But I wouldn't know. I guess he just meant to write what I wrote above, but the notation eludes me.

Comment: So really we should be integrating both sides w.r.t. $t$, not integrating one w.r.t. $v$ and one w.r.t. $r$?

Comment: @EricAuld One always integrates with respect to the same variable. Here the variable is $t$. When one write $dr/r^2$ one is really writing $r'(t)dt/r(t)^2$, at best. Note I avoided $dt,dr,dv$ for such reasons.

Comment: @EricAuld one side you are integrating wrt 'v' and another side wrt 'r'. This is common problem in physics. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34382/first-integral-of-an-equation-of-motion-mu-ddot-r-frackr2/34385#34385) might be helpful

Comment: @experimentX Can you elaborate a bit on why you've used quotes around $v$ and $r$? Are they really standing for something more precise?

Comment: I think it is clearer if you follow Peter's lead. You are integrating both sides with respect to $t$. When you are comfortable with the approach you can take shortcuts (as in $\int v dv$ instead of $\int r'(t) r''(t) dt$). I think skipping tiny steps like this when teaching confuses many students.

Comment: @EricAuld 'v' stands for the velocity and 'r' stands for the (radial vector) distance between two particles. the problem has been formulated for two particles with no initial velocities. The solution must be such that two particles converge with each other. If they had initial velocities, then approach would have been a bit different resulting in elliptical orbit.

Answer (score 0):

[I'm assuming that your problem is 1-D, *i.e.*, that the particles move towards/away from each other on a straight line. Please comment if this is not the case. I also assume WLOG that $r_0 = x_2(0) - x_1(0) > 0$. I define $v = \dot{x}_2-\dot{x}_1$ - *i.e.*, without the absolute values - since I am only interested in the time interval up to collision. That such an interval $[0,\bar{t}]$ exists follows from the initial conditions & continuity of the solutions.]

The question is legitimate, because it can very well happen that the same $r$ will be achieved at different times $t_2 > t_1 \ge 0$; it must hence hold that $v(t_2)=v(t_1)$, for $v$ to be a well-defined function. Think, in particular, of the two masses shot at speeds $\dot{x}_2(0)>\dot{x}_1(0)>0$ (both along the line joining them, of course). In that case, the distance $x_2(t)-x_1(t)$ will initially increase (because $\dot{x}_2(0)-\dot{x}_1(0) > 0$); if the velocity difference is less than the escape velocity, the distance will then decrease until it hits zero (collision).

Note, now, that your two-body system conserves energy and momentum (that's physics, but it's of course also supported by the math). Hence,
$$
\frac{1}{2} m \left(\dot{x}_1^2+\dot{x}_2^2\right) - \frac{Gm^2}{r^2} = E = const.
\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\left(\dot{x}_1+\dot{x}_2\right) = \frac{P}{m} =: V = const.
$$
I can write the energy conservation relation as
$$
\frac{1}{2} m \left(\dot{x}_1-\dot{x}_2\right)^2 + m \dot{x}_1 (V - \dot{x}_1) - \frac{Gm^2}{r^2} = E
$$
that is,

$$
\frac{1}{2} m v^2 = E + \frac{Gm^2}{r^2} - m \dot{x}_1 (V - \dot{x}_1) .
$$

For $v(r)$ to be well-defined (*up to a sign* - but we had already imagined that), we need that the third and final term in the RHS is the same at times $t_1$ and $t_2$. Can you examine whether this is true :)?